# ExcelDataReader Error on Web Server - Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))

Tags: c#, webserver, exceldatareader

I am attempting to write results of records being updated to an Excel file using ExcelDataReader after each successful update.  Currently, the functionality works fine on my machine running thru Visual Studio, however, once this same functionality is executed from our web server, the following error occurs:

> Error: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following
>   error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

I am not sure, at this point, how to solve this error at this point.  PLEASE HELP.

My codebehind for the executing code is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using BL.WebUserProvider;
using VO.WebUserProvider;
using System.Data;
using Excel;

    private void ExportDataSetToExcel(DataSet ds)
        {

            // Export Data into EXCEL Sheet
            ApplicationClass ExcelApp = new ApplicationClass();
            ExcelApp.Application.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);

            // Write data into excel sheet cells
            for (int i = 1; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count + 2; i++) // Row Count accounts for "Column" row and itteration starting at index 1 (Confusing...I know)
            {
                for (int j = 1; j < ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count + 1; j++)
                {
                    if (i == 1)
                        ExcelApp.Cells[i, j] = ds.Tables[0].Columns[j - 1].ToString();
                    else
                        ExcelApp.Cells[i, j] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i - 2][j - 1].ToString();
                }
            }

            // save excel file 
            ExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs(string.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}  {3}.{4}.{5} - {6} records.xlsx",
                DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, DateTime.Now.Hour, DateTime.Now.Minute, DateTime.Now.Second, ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count));

            ExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook.Saved = true;
            ExcelApp.Quit();
        }
```

Comment: 1st daft but necessary question, is Excel definitely installed on the server?

Comment: MS Office is not installed on the server, nor is the MS Excel application.  Does it matter if it is or not since the file will be written to the client's machine?

Comment: If this code is running on the server and you are referencing an Excel assembly to do it then yes you need to have Excel installed on the server. Which I might add is not supported by Microsoft, although it can be done.

Comment: I installed Excel onto the web server and the error is still occurring.  Any additional ideas?

Comment: Installing it onto the server isn't enough. You have to be running your web application under a user that has previously logged in interactively and started up Excel. And you need to configure DCOM settings to allow Excel to be started up by a service. I should add that this whole setup is complicated and error prone, so seriously if there is another way you can possibly provide this service for your users I would consider that. Office on a server being used by a web application should be a last resort

Comment: The warnings: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757

Comment: The alternatives: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23707475/dcom-config-settings-for-microsoft-interop-word-automation

Comment: We have another way that uses SSRS to generate the Excel file.  I will attempt to do it this way.  Thank you. I don't know how to "up-vote" this since it's a comment.

Comment: That sounds like a better job. There's also the option of OpenXml I think.